# creating custom time algorith like timeago in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, datetime, time

I want a custom time algorithm like javascript. I was able to achieve this using php but am not able to do the same with javascript!

WHat i had in php was like.....
[***PHP FIDDLE***](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e02728e4944694d5ece241b8ae5fd076fbca481e)(***i want something like this in js output***)

```
 function getTime($mytime){
//    $mytime  is a datetime sql database format time
    $thetime = strtotime($mytime);
    $q = new DateTime($mytime);
    $current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
    $w = new DateTime($current_time);
    $result = $w ->diff($q);

$string = "";
$year = $result->y;
$month = $result->m;
$day = $result->d;
$hour = $result->h;
$min = $result->i;
$sec = $result->s; 
if($year==0){
   if($month==0){
     if($day==0){
        if($hour==0){       
        if($min==0){
          if($sec <30){
           $string .= "Just now";}else if($sec<60){ $string .= "A few seconds ago";}                
        }else{
         if($min<5){$string .="A few minutes ago";}else if($min>=5){$string .=$min . ' minutes ago'; }              
        }}else{
         if($hour<6){$string .=$hour . ' hours ago';}else if($hour>=6){
            $chour = (date('H',$thetime));
            if( ($chour>=5)&&($chour<=17) ){$string .= 'Today at ' .date('h.m a',$thetime);}else{$string .= 'Tonight at '. date('h.m a',$thetime);}}                
        }}else{ 
           if($day==1){$string .= "Yesterday at " . date('h:m a',$thetime);}else if(($day>1) && ($day<=7)){$string .= $day . " days ago";}else if($day>7){$string .= date('M, d',$thetime) . ' at '. date('h:i a',$thetime);}           
        }}else{ 
         if($month<5){$string .=$month . ' months ago'; }else if($month>=5){$string .= date('M,d',$thetime) .' at ' . date('h.i a',$thetime) ;}             
        }}else{     
        $string .=date('dS M , Y',$thetime) .' at '. date('h.i a',$thetime);        
        }

 return $string;
 }
```

What i thought was to dynamically update time using javascript! so i did this......

```
$(function(){
    var $second = 1000;
    var $minute = $second * 60;
    var $hour = $minute * 60;
    var $day = $hour * 24;

    setInterval(function(){
        $('.comment').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $time = new Date($this.attr('datetime'));
            var $now = new Date();

            var $distance = $now - $time;

            var $days = Math.floor($distance / $day);
            var $hours = Math.floor(($distance % $day) / $hour);
            var $minutes = Math.floor(($distance % $hour) / $minute);
            var $seconds = Math.floor(($distance % $minute) / $second);

            var $time_string = '';

            if($days > 0) {
                $time_string = $time_string + $days + ' Day(s) ';
            }

            if($hours > 0) {
                $time_string = $time_string + $hours + ' Hour(s) ';
            }

            if($minutes > 0) {
                $time_string = $time_string + $minutes + ' Minute(s) ';
            }

            if($seconds > 0) {
                $time_string = $time_string + $seconds + ' Second(s)';
            }

            $this.text($time_string);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

but his outputs something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Jp7/) here.
What i wanted is like my prev. php output i.e `X min ago or X seconds ago or 12 May 2014 etc` how do i implement my above `php` code with this `js` ?

Comment: What's the problem? Just add similar checks like `if ($distance < 30 * $second)` to return `just now`.

Comment: cannot just get it maybe an answer with better explanation will help i am a newbie!

Comment: You managed to write the first code. The logic is exactly the same.

Comment: i have `$month` `$day` in php but in js i dont have those ! @Barmar

Comment: Maybe look at `Moment.js`, it might have some helpful functions for you.

Comment: I DONT WANT ANY PLUGINS! my question states `custom` not readymade!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54146/discussion-between-hackermaniac-and-barmar).

Comment: You do have month, day and such, see the [documentation of Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: can u present an answer @Kicsi

Comment: @HackerManiac just copy-paste your php funxtion into javascript and change DateTime to Date, $result->m to result->getMonth(), etc. There is no need to rewrite the code, just change the syntax.

Comment: i dont get it! what is `result` in js ? @Kicsi maybe u can do it for me plz!

Comment: @Kicsi used $distance.getMonth() but getting an error `undefined is not a function` !

Comment: @HackerManiac you should have started with that. In js if you subtract 2 dates, you get a number(time difference in miniseconds) and not a date. Use var $distance = new Date($now - $time); instead.

Comment: since i dont have any function like `date('format',$time)` in js how do i do those in javascript see the `$string .=....` lines of codes in `.php` file @Kicsi